# GUI Qt global variables error

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I'm doing a GUI interface using QtCreator and C++.
I'm also using a ROS node to act according to my interface and for that I need to create some global variables to change when I call a callback in the gui.

I started by creating a header file called globals.h like I saw in some post and wrote the following:

**globals.h**

```
#ifndef GLOBALS_H
#define GLOBALS_H

extern int numberM;
extern int duty[16];
extern int place[16];

#endif // GLOBALS_H
```

Then in the mainwindow.cpp (that is created automatically when I create a GUI using Qt and where I write the callbacks) I did the following:

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "globals.h"

namespace
{
int numberM;
int duty;
int place;
}
```

However, when I try to do something as numberM = 0 it gives me the following error:

> mainwindow.cpp:18: error: reference to 'numberM' is ambiguous numberM
>   = 0;

I guess I didn't understand correctly how the global variables work in this case. It's a bit confusing. Do I need to also declare the globals.h in the mainwindow.h file, or what am I missing/doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`extern` means that your variables would be defined without initialization. So you header is correct/ you just need to initialize you global variables

P.S. also for enabling you code just use a name for you namespace

```
namespace global {
  int numberM;
}
int foo() {
  global::numberM = 3;
}
```